# Can you rename symbol once it’s saved in style Reference in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, style

Is there a way to rename a symbol in Style Reference file without deleting the file and starting all over again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can open the Style file in Microsoft Access and open up the table, then edit the name. For example with line symbols see this screen shot.

Make sure you close ArcMap, then open up the style file in Access. Make the change, then close Access.

The style file might be stored in this folder:
*C:\Users\matthew\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.3\ArcMap*
[image]